# javascript scope not actually global

Tags: javascript, function, scope

```js
var _gquill;
var _gform;

function quillFunctionSetup(quillvar, quillformvar, quillsubmitvar) {   
    _gquill = new Quill("#".concat(quillvar), {
        modules: { toolbar: true },
        theme: 'snow'
    });
   
    _gform = document.getElementById(quillformvar);
    _gform.onsubmit = function(quillsubmitvar, _gquill) {     
        var about = document.getElementById(quillsubmitvar);       
        about.value = _gquill.container.firstChild.innerHTML;
        return false;
    };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.quilljs.com/1.0.0/quill.snow.css" rel="stylesheet">
<form action="{% url 'SecurityTarget:stview' ST_Title.id %}" method="post" id="overviewform">
  <div id="quilleditor" >{{ST_Title.OverviewDescription}}</div>
  <input type="hidden" name = "new_overview" id="new_overview"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Save Toe Overview" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">quillFunctionSetup("quilleditor", "overviewform", "new_overview");</script>
```

So this doesn't work and I am having trouble understanding why. so the quill portion works fine, and when it was a script defined in line with the html everything worked great. I moved it to the header and then nothing worked because the elements weren't defined yet? so I wrapped it in a function and called it inline, but then my submit button stopeed functioning which I still don't know why, but 
`function(quillsubmitvar, _gquill)`
adding quillsubmitvar to the line above (it originally wasn't there made it work) which makes no sense sense this is within the scope of the original function.

and still with this code

```
about.value
```

never gets assigned ??
also when running this script in this editor it says undefined reference to the function

```
quillFunctionSetup
```

but it is defined in the header, and it runs on my website?? I am so confused any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your code is not valid, please share a valid code.

Comment: why isn't it valid? my browser and django say it is?

Comment: In the future, please make sure your code is nicely indented. It's hard to follow otherwise. The line `$(form).serializeArray());` is definitely invalid syntax. I'm guessing that was supposed to be on the comment line.

Comment: `_gform.onsubmit = function(quillsubmitvar, _gquill) ` expects new values passed in. Context of those parameters inside the function is not the same as outside the function

Comment: Sorry, my bad...

Comment: You need to move the `quillFunctionSetup(...)` function call outside of the form element (place it after `</form>`). You're currently attempting to call `document.getElementById` on something that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: @jmcgriz ok I moved it outside but I still have the same problem.

Comment: @charlietfl  so brackets don't indicate scope in javascript? sorry I have programmed in many languages but am new to javascript

Comment: They do (sort of, `var` is function scoped though), but this doesn't seem to be related to scope but is on execution order and script placement.

Comment: no, those are the expected function arguments and since you named them the same they are completely different variables inside vs  outside

Comment: @Jacob sorry  I removed $(form).serializeArray()); and updated by indents and comments to make it more legible

Comment: @noone392 ah, now that it's been cleaned up, I see the issue. This line is wrong `_gform.onsubmit = function(quillsubmitvar, _gquill) {`, it should just be `function()`. As it stands, you're overwriting the value of `quillsubmitvar`, because `onsubmit` is passing an `event` object as the first parameter

Comment: @jmcgriz wait I don't understand, because I thought per Jacob, that those variable wouldn't be accessible inside the event otherwise...? so is there a way to pass arguments into an event function?

Comment: @noone392 You shouldn't, the way the scoping works, it's picking up from the closure in which it's defined, so it already has access to those variables. I'll include an answer that explains it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in this line: `_gform.onsubmit = function(quillsubmitvar, _gquill) {`

In this case`quillsubmitvar` and `_gquill` aren't being passed in, they're being listed as the names of the parameters that will be passed to that function, in the same way that the first declaration works `function quillFunctionSetup(quillvar, quillformvar, quillsubmitvar) {`

Javascript is lexically scoped, meaning that anything within `quillFunctionSetup` already has access to the other variables defined within that closure and anything outside of it, but nothing defined within a separate closure elsewhere (not applicable in this case).

```
_gform.onsubmit = function() {     
    var about = document.getElementById(quillsubmitvar);       
    about.value = _gquill.container.firstChild.innerHTML;
    return false;
};
```

Should work as expected

Comment: Thank you jmcgriz. When I do that my submit button no longer does anything, I mean the past never posts at all.

Comment: Right, and it shouldn't. `return false` interrupts the form post. If you want it to continue with the form post after assigning to `about.value`, you'll need to remove `return false`

Comment: I wish I could thumbs up this answer more then once! thank you very much!